# how to open remote desktop connection using robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

How do i achieve below using robot framework. SSHLibrary is not of any help

Using Remote Desktop, log into the web server.  Using Windows Explorer navigate to the /folder1 for the web (for instance, \abc\W\india\1.exe).  Doubleclick on the executable file: 1.exe

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Microsoft SysInternals [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) you can open a terminal session to a windows box and execute commands like you would normally.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a batch or powershell script that does what you want, and then write a robot framework keyword that calls that batch or powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

The preceding answers by Bryan Oakley and A. Kootstra are what I would go for.

If you specifically need to interact with a Windows GUI application, you might want to try the [Robot Framework AutoIT Library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/). [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) works pretty well for Windows GUI apps and is a whole language (BASIC-style) to itself. Otherwise, if it *can* be done via command-line, I'd go with one of their answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, besides robot framework. SSHLibrary you need to install a SSH server in the remote windows machine https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows

hope that helps